# Broken screen and touch

Tags: htc-one, broken-screen

I have a HTC One M7 and long story short the screen is completely destroyed but the phone still works because i still get beeps and LED blinks when someone messeges me. I would like to get my pictures and contacts off of it but when i try i have to unlock the phone to get a access to the files and the touch screen is broken so that isnt possible. Also i cant see whats happening on the screen which makes the situation even worse. Can someone please help me get my files off without having to physically put in the pattern. Please and thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! Have you already checked with our [broken-screen tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info)? Several hints and first-aid there. If you've checked already, what did you try and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

If you have rooted your phone you can try to use [android control](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2786395). It allows you to see the screen and touch the screen through ADB but it is a bit hard to get working sometimes.

If you can see the screen you can try an USB OTG cable with a USB mouse attached to it. I had this for a week when my touch broke down physically, people tend to look at you weird with this but it works quite well.